# Taylor series for non linear system

Tags: taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

In Dormand-Prince original paper for Runge Kutta 4(5) formula (link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0771050X80900133?via%3Dihub), at the beginning, it is noted that the equation

```
y' = f(t, y(t))
```

by taking t'=1, **without the loss of generality**, simplifies to

```
y' = f(y(t))
```

And then it procedes with taylor series expansion of y by using simplified equation. Now the question is, Is the taylor series expansion of y by using any of the above equations are equivalent? That is, Is taking

```
y'' = df(t,y(t))/dt + df(t,y(t))/dy * f
```

is equal to

```
y'' = df(y(t))/dy * f.
```

If not how we do not lose generality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same, you just extend the system of ODE and thus the Jacobi matrix and other derivative tensors by some trivial constant columns by adding the time as a state component.

---

If the paper did state it the way you cited it, then they mean that instead of considering the class of general ODE $y'=f(t,y)$, it is sufficient (and shorter in terms of notation, which is why they did that) to consider the class of autonomous ODE $y'=\tilde f(\tilde y)$, where $\tilde y=(t,y)=(t,y_1,...,y_n)$ and $\tilde f=(1,f)=(1,f_1,...,f_n)$. In the citation this is shortly indicated by the hint that $t'=1$ is added to the system as additional equation, with $t$ implied as additional state component.

---

Using different letters instead of modifiers, set $u=\pmatrix{t\\y}$ and $u'=F(u)=\pmatrix{1\\f(t,y)}$ according to $t'=\frac{dt}{dt}=1$. Then for the second derivative of $u$ you get
$$
u''=F'(u)u'=F'(u)F(u)=\pmatrix{0&0\\\partial_tf(t,y)&\partial_yf(t,y)}\pmatrix{1\\f(t,y)}
=\pmatrix{0\\\partial_tf(t,y)+\partial_yf(t,y)f(t,y)}.
$$
This has the expected entries in the "non-trivial" positions.

Comment: Just consider y'(t) = y + t^2. Then you get y'' = y + t^2 + 2t and y'' = y + t^2.

Comment: How do you get the second one? $y''=f_t+f_yy'=2t+1\cdot (y+t^2)$.

Comment: As in my question I gave two equations which are said to be equivalent.

Comment: I do not see it. I only see that in the question you made no distinction of the ODE function of the original autonomous system and the modified, extended, autonomous system, which I named $F$ for that reason. The second is vector valued, while the first is scalar.

Comment: Can you please explain how the y' = f(y) and y' = f(t,y) can be equivalent. I would expect y''(t) to be same which is df/dt. But in the example I gave it is not the same.

Comment: Or, could you please, put y' = y + t^2 into a form of y' = f(y).

Comment: I did give this form already in my answer, set $u=\pmatrix{t\\y}$ then the equivalent autonomous system is $\dot u=F(u)=\pmatrix{1\\f(t,y)}=\pmatrix{1\\y+t^2}$. If you want, you can replace the named components $t,y$ with the more anonymous $u_0,u_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought it is elimination of the explicit dependence on t. However it is rather just a change of notation.

Comment: Yes, only half or a third of the terms in the Taylor expansions, and the Butcher trees are also more simple to introduce and discuss.